# Changing the URL for the "reset password" woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I'm using WooCommerce on my website and I've created a custom login and a sign up page. Instead of seeing the standard `my-account` login page, new users are taken to a custom login page. This links to a custom register page if users click the link.

Both these pages work fine. The problem comes when creating a *lost your password* section. Originally users would be taken to `my-account/lost-password` but since I wanted to build custom pages, I needed to create a new lost password page.

I've got this page working correctly. Once a user has input their username or password and clicked the button, an email is sent to them with a url link that they need to click in order to be taken to the page that allows them to reset their password. This is where I'm having problems.

Originally users would be taken to the `my-account` page but as I'm avoiding this, I want users to have to use my own custom page.

The code in the email that specifies the url users need to go to is like so:

```
<a class="link" href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'key' => $reset_key, 'login' => rawurlencode( $user_login ) ), wc_get_endpoint_url( 'lost-password', '', wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Click here to reset your password', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
```

How do i get the above url to point to my custom page and allow users to reset their password. I did manage to get the url to direct me to my own page but changing it to:

```
<a class="link" href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'key' => $reset_key, 'login' => rawurlencode( $user_login ) ), get_page_link(1839) ) ) ; ?>"><?php _e( 'Click here to reset your password', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
```

**But** it did not update the users password when they reset it.

---

**UPDATE**
It seems that this issue is something to do with the `$reset_key` and `$user_login` not being passed to my custom form. When using:

```
<a class="link" href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'key' => $reset_key, 'login' => rawurlencode( $user_login ) ), wc_get_endpoint_url( 'lost-password', '', wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ) ); ?>">
```

there are hidden inputs on my form that have values of `$reset_key` and `$user_login`, however, when using:

```
<a class="link" href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'key' => $reset_key, 'login' => rawurlencode( $user_login ) ), wc_get_endpoint_url( 'lost-password', '', wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Click here to reset your password', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
```

these hidden inputs have no values.

Is there a way to pass these parameters to my custom form, allowing the hidden inputs to be populated and the user's password be updated?

Answer (score 6):

Reset the forgot password URL from WooCommerce to WordPress.

Because you have to be logged in to view the site, the forgot password was unable to access the WooCommerce Page.

Adding this to *functions.php* resets the password URL to the WordPress URL.

```php
// Wordpress + WooCommerce Reset Password URL
function reset_pass_url()
{
    $siteURL = get_option('siteurl');
    return "{$siteURL}/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword";
}
add_filter('lostpassword_url', 'reset_pass_url', 11, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using Jquery.  :)

```
function changeReseturl(){

jQuery(".woocommerce-LostPassword.lost_password a").attr('href','your-login-url');

}

add_action('wp_footer','changeReseturl');
```

Comment: Why on earth would you use jQuery for this??

Comment: The code snippet won't work, PHP and JS code is mixed, you would have to wrap the JS into a script tag